# How to make an exception if input is not digit

Tags: c#

How can I make and exception if input from `Console.ReadLine` is not digit?

```
    while (price != -1)
    {
        
        subtotal = subtotal + price;
        Console.Write("Value: [-1 to exit]");
        price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());      
        
    }
```

Comment: `if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLIne(), out price)) {...}`

Comment: Er, you don't need to do anything. If the input isn't numeric you'll get an exception with the code you already have

Answer (score 1):

That is why [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-6.0) has been designed: instead of converting, having format exception, catching them etc.

```
price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

you can put

```
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out price))
  Console.WriteLine("Syntax error. Please, try again. Value: [-1 to exit]");

// from now on, price is a valid double
```

**Code:**

```
while (price != -1) {
  subtotal = subtotal + price;
  Console.Write("Value: [-1 to exit]");
  
  while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out price))
    Console.WriteLine("Syntax error. Please, try again. Value: [-1 to exit]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For things like this I usually recommend that you make a method that asks a question and gives back an answer, or repeats the question if the input is invalid:

```
private double AskDouble(string question){
  double result = 0;
  do {
    Console.Write(question);
  } while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
  return result;
}
```

You can then neatly use this for multiple times where you need a number:

```
double weight = AskDouble("Enter your weight in kg: ");
double height = AskDouble("Enter your height in m: ");
double age = AskDouble("Enter your age in years: ");
```